# Make network-manager pick any available wifi device

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

I'm using NetworkManager (Arch) together with USB Wifi dongles and I would like to setup a wifi connection profile to pick whatever wifi device is available. In other words, I want to set a SSID+Password for a particular wifi network and I want to be able to configure it so that any wifi USB device plugged would try to connect to that network.

For example if I force plug out USB card X and plug in Y, I want Y to automatically connect to the wifi network. If I plug Y card, with X one still plugged in (and connected to that SSID), the Y card should stay idle until I plug out X, then Y should try to initiate the connection.

The problem is that nmcli wants me to provide an interface name which I don't know in advance. I use traditional kernel network name policy configuration (wlan0, wlan1, etc) but the wildcard in nmcli (ie. `wlan*`) doesn't seem to work. The wildcard `*` also doesn't work as in both cases I get the following error when I try to bring the connection `up`:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device br-623baa8caefa not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).
```

(the `br-` device is a docker bridge network interface and it's being picked up even if I use `wlan*` as the ifname)

Ideally I don't want to create 10 profiles ranging from wlan0 to wlan9 with same SSID (unless there's no other way).